# Error using AngularJS: "Diff is not defined"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'm working on a project using AngularJS and Sails. Trying to run the webapp, I found the following error:

```
 ReferenceError: diff is not defined
 at http://localhost:1337/js/angular-sails-bind.js:108:38
 at Object.fn (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/angular.min.js:117:478)
 at k.$digest (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/angular.min.js:119:35)
 at k.$apply (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/angular.min.js:121:460)
 at http://localhost:1337/js/angular-sails-bind.js:180:28
 at c.serverResponded (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js:362:11)
 at c.onPacket (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js:2:20375)
 at d.onPacket (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js:2:16703)
 at c.onPacket (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js:2:10676)
 at c.onData (http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js:2:10413)
```

I tried to update and use the latest version of Angle, and nothing. Anyone know what is the reason?

Comment: It seems that diff is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the function is in the new version of the library, in the "dist" directory. Sorry,

The function:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
return arr1.filter(function (i) {
    return arr2.indexOf(i) < 0;
});
}
```